# Problems with the widows 10 wireless network adapter driver

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, drivers, network-adapter

So I started having problems with the "Qualcomm Atheros QCA61X4A" wireless network adapter for the windows 10.

At first it would just stop working and all I had to do was to scan for hardware changes and it would get back to working, if happened a little then stopped for a while.
until recently were it would stop working again, only that this time the "Qualcomm Atheros QCA61X4A" would just go missing from the network adapters on the device manager.

And now it keeps going on and off, going missing and showing up again, Right now it did it again of going missing then back and now it just stopped working and the troubleshoot says its having driver/network issues, I disabled and enabled as a last effort for today and seems to be staying... kind of, but I think the problem will come back.

I haven't really found a good solution and wanted to know if someone has one or at least is in the same situation, is it a Windows 10 bug? Could I have accidentally messed up? Would appreciate any help! Thank you.

(Add. Also, the troubleshooter did say that it wasn't properly installed but I already tried uninstalling it so it could reinstall itself, didn't seem to have done much.)

Answer (score 1):

I am quite sure it is not a Windows bug, rather I would say the card has gone intermittent and that was confirmed by the troubleshooter saying the card was not properly installed (but you have already uninstalled / installed the card).  You might see if there is a newer driver available.

May I suggest at this point you try an inexpensive wireless USB adapter and see if this works reliably (probably will)